# ScktComp.hpp is missing in RAD Studio 10.3

Tags: vcl, rad-studio, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am currently migrating an old project from Borland C++Builder 5 to Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3 Rio.

Since the old project is not easily portable, I needed to recreate all the units and forms in a new RAD Studio project.

This has been going fine until I encountered a file which uses the `ScktComp.hpp` file.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where I might find and how I can include this file in my project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` components have been deprecated for a LONG time, and are [no longer installed by default](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Installing_Socket_Components).  If you want to use them, you must install them manually.  But, you really should rewrite the old code to use an up-to-date socket library, such as [Indy](https://www.indyproject.org) (which is pre-installed in the IDE), or to just use Microsoft's WinSock API directly (which is what the old components use internally).

That being said, if you must use the old socket components, then know that the `ScktComp.hpp` header file was renamed to `System.Win.ScktComp.hpp` in C++Builder XE2 (read up about [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Scope_Names)).  A legacy `ScktComp.hpp` header file was provided *for backwards compatibility* (`#include`'ing the new header file internally) but [it was eliminated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/What's_New#Removal_of_Legacy_Headers) in C++Builder 10.1 Berlin (XE8 and 10.0 Seattle warned users that legacy headers were being deprecated for future removal).

So, from 10.1 onward, you must use the new `System.Win.ScktComp.hpp` file directly, the legacy `ScktComp.hpp` file no longer exists.